# Using the app.scss file in an ionic 3 project

Tags: sass, stylesheet, ionic3, styling

Today I've started using ionic 3 for the first time. I don't really know anything about it, so that's why I wanna learn how it works.

I've created a sidemenu project and now I want to add some global styling in my app.scss, so I can use it in any page of my project. Well, I've added simple styling to my app.scss but nothing happens on my page. Everything still looks the same. Now my question is: Do I have to import the app.scss somewhere? If so, where? Or how can I use the app.scss?

I thought it would happen automatically, that my page uses also the classes of my app.scss and not only of it's own stylesheet, but to me it seems like it doesn't even know the classes of the app.scss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the ***app.scss*** you can create class use them normally as `class="class-name"` on html.

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I did but it doesn't change the styling on my page. I also think that it's a bit weird because it can't be that difficult just to add some global styling but it just doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: I use it this way `ion-app {  .warning { color: color($colors, warning);  } }`. its work for me.

Comment: Post your **app.scss** on question, please.

Comment: lol i forgot to put it in the ion-app brackets. now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use it, no need to import it anywhere. A few things to keep in mind though:

There are things you would like to add at a global scope like for example if you want to enable newlines in toast messages you add the following:

```
.toast-message {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

If you want to add something only for iOS you add it as a sub element of the ios class:

```
.ios {
  ... // your iOS-specific css rules
}
```

If you want to add somehing only for Android (material design) you add it as a sub element of the md class:

```
.md {
 ... // your android-specific css rules
}
```

An there is also a `wp` class for windows phone if you should need it.

Make sure you have a look at [ionics theming docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming).